# show a jQuery dialog-confirm before submitting, on Laravel

Tags: jquery, dialog, laravel-5.4

I wish understand how show a jQuery dialog-confirm before effectively submitting the form's data to a database.

i'm new in Laravel programming, my version is 5.4, and my intention is to understand the flow of the thing. i'll post my controller, my form view and my jQuery dialog-confirm script. I will be grateful if someone explains me how to put in communication these three pages. thanks in advance.
(I want to specify that i have already appended the jQuery and the jQueryUI code lines in a view called `master.blade.php`, that is inherited in every child view, and that jqueryUI methods like `draggable()` work).

below the form view: index.blade.php

```
`<div class="col-md-4">
          <form method="POST" action="/localities/create">
          {{csrf_field()}}
              <h2>Add Locality</h2>
              <p>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">paese/città</label><br>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                </div>
              </p>
              <p>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add &raquo;</button>
                </div>
              </p>
          </form>
        </div>`
```

below the controller: LocalitiesController.php

```
`<?php`

`namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Locality;
use Validator;`

`class LocalitiesController extends Controller
{
    public function store(){`

        //validate the input
        $this->validate(request(),[

            'name'=>'required'
        ]);

        //create a new locality
        Locality::create(['name'=>request('name')]);

        //redirect to back
        return back();

    }
`}`
```

below the javascript code, as script.blade.php

```
 `<div id="dialog-confirm">`
    `<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>are you sure?</p>
  </div>`



  `<script type="text/javascript">
            $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: "auto",
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Sospendi": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });
  </script>`
```